# C# Dictionary with StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase giving error while trying to add case insensitive key

Tags: c#, dictionary, generics

Trying out code,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> paramList = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        paramList.Add("LastUpdatedByUserName", "123");
        paramList.Add("LastUpdatedbyUserName", "124");
        
        Console.WriteLine(paramList["LastUpdatedbyUserName"]);
    }
}
```

This is giving me an error saying,

```
Run-time exception (line 11): An item with the same key has already been added.
```

Comment: So basically to allow case insensitive keys, I need to drop StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.

Comment: You told the dictionary to treat strings that are different only in the letter case of characters as identical. So you should not be surprised when after adding an element with a given key, attempting to add another element using the same key according to the case-insensitive comparer you provided throws the expected exception. If you want case-insensitive keys, don't try to add the same key twice; if you want to be able to use keys that differ only in case, then don't use a case-insensitive comparer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In Dictionary, the key cannot be null, but value can be.
- In Dictionary, key must be unique. Duplicate keys are not allowed if
  you try to use duplicate key then compiler will throw an exception as you get.

Watch out that in your example there is a slight difference between the keys that *LastUpdated`B`yUserName* and *LastUpdated`b`yUserName*

The constructor expects an [`IEqualityComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.80).aspx) which tells the dictionary how to compare keys.

[`StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.invariantcultureignorecase.aspx) gives you an `IEqualityComparer` instance which compares strings in a case-insensitive manner.